# Converting a cURL to pyCurl equivalent

Tags: python, json, curl, pycurl

I have a Patch request using cURL, now i want to use this with python:

```
curl -X Patch -H "content-type: application/json" -d '{"activation": {"mode":"activate_immediate"},"transport_params":[{"destination_ip":"239.255.255.50","destination_port": 5004, "rtp_enabled": True, "source_ip": "192.168.10.115","source_port":"auto"}]}' http://ip:port/x-nmos/connection/v1.2/single/uuid/staged
```

Can anyone help me with the pyCurl equivalent or any other way i can do this using python?

Comment: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/

Comment: Do you want make a GET?

Comment: Dont use pycurl. It is a nightmare. Use requests instead.

Comment: @MichelGuimarães I want to make a PATCH request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I advice you to use the `request` lib instead of `pyCurl`, as mentioned by @Z4-tier. Try:

```
import requests
headers = {"content-type": "application/json"}
data = {"activation": {"mode":"activate_immediate"},"transport_params":[{"destination_ip":"239.255.255.50","destination_port": 5004, "rtp_enabled": True, "source_ip": "192.168.10.115","source_port":"auto"}]}
url = "http://IP:PORT/x-nmos/connection/v1.0/single/UUID/staged"
resquest = requests.patch(url = url, data = data, headers = headers)
```

I couldn't complete the request because of a ip or port error. Be sure the request body is correct!

Comment: Sorry, i could not share IP, PORT and UUID due to security issues.

I actually tried `requests` before, i get `<Response [200]>` but when i try to print the contents of the response, it is empty. The contents of the response should contain the updated parameters as far as i know. Do you have any idea what might be causing the issue.